# Send("{DOWN}") on a context menu doesn't work everytime

Tags: eclipse, automation, ui-automation, autoit

I am automating Eclipse IDE on a Windows 10 system. I need to search for "QueueManagers" in a SysTreeView32, select it, right-click it to open the context menu and move to "Open in new window". AutoIt Window Information Tool shows only class of the context menu.

[inspect tool image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKoQl.jpg)

So I used `Send("{DOWN}")` three times. This sometimes doesn't start from top of context menu and [chooses the wrong option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d54Wd.png):

```
#AutoIt3Wrapper_UseX64=y
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#include <GuiTreeView.au3>

WinActivate("eclipse-workspace - Trial/src/module-info.java - Eclipse IDE")
Sleep(1000)

Local $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("eclipse-workspace - Trial/src/module-info.java - Eclipse IDE", "", "SysTreeView321")
;MsgBox(0, "Handle", $hWnd)
Sleep(1000)

Local $searchText = "QueueManagers"
$hItemFound = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, $searchText)
;MsgBox(0, "Result", $hItemFound)

If $hItemFound Then
    Sleep(1000)
    _GUICtrlTreeView_ClickItem($hWnd, $hItemFound)
    _GUICtrlTreeView_ClickItem($hWnd, $hItemFound, "right")

    Send("{DOWN}")
    Send("{DOWN}")
    Send("{DOWN}")
EndIf
```

Using `Sleep()` I got the same results. How to make `Send("")` start from top? Is there another way to search for "Open in new window" in the context menu and click that?

Comment: Do you see the underlined letters in each menu option? If you press that key it should select that menu item. For example `N` for "open in new window"

Comment: @garbb Is it possible to search for "open in new window" and then click that?

Comment: "This works sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't start from top of context menu and chooses the wrong option." There mostly is never such thing as "sometimes" working, you gotta look for a pattern when the misclick happens. 

Maybe the cursor of your mouse is interfiering with your code? Maybe you have to send a MouseMove beforehand so it doesn't affect the context menu?

btw. you can use the return of "WinActivate" as the window handle :)

Comment: @mhaendler When the program executes, I don't touch the mouse and the cursor is in the center. The context menu is on the left.